# Likert plot with neutrals held aside

Tags: r, plot, likert

I'm using the likert package to create plots of a questionnaire. I would like to create a plot like this, where neutral responses are held aside, do you know if there is a way to do it in R?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A cheap example how to reproduce the plot

```
lst <- c("I dislike them a lot",
         "I dislike them",
         "I like them", 
         "I like them a lot",
"Neutrals and Don’t know")
levels(dftest$Bounty)
dftest <-  tibble(Bounty = sample(lst, 100, replace = T),
                  Snickers = sample(lst, 100, replace = T),
                  `Milky Way` = sample(lst, 100, replace = T),
                  Mars = sample(lst, 100, replace = T),
                  `Galaxy Caramel` = sample(lst, 100, replace = T),
                  Twix = sample(lst, 100, replace = T),
                  Galaxy = sample(lst, 100, replace = T),
                  `Maltese Teaser` = sample(lst, 100, replace = T)) %>%
        mutate(across(.fns = ~as.factor(.))) %>%
        mutate(across(.fns = ~ordered(., levels = lst)))
plot_likert(dftest,   cat.neutral = 5,   legend.pos = "all",
            geom.colors = c( "#D57141", "#E4AE8E", "#466484", "#869CB0",
                            "#C8CDD1")) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: What package does `plot_likert()` come from??

Comment: `sjPlot::plot_likert()`. The package required some additional dependencies, though